# How can the Investigators banish Abhoth permanently?

Tags: published-adventures, call-of-cthulhu

In *Dunwich: Return to the Forgotten Village*, the God Abhoth dwells below the ground, spreading its filth and decay.

Normally, Mythos Gods are associated with Call/Dismiss spells. The Call spell brings the god into our world and the Dismiss spell forces it back to its own dimension.

Abhoth, however does not have a Call/Dismiss spell listed. The adventure does state that the Mi-Go summoned Abhoth many thousands of years ago, so there must be some form of summoning spell.

So, how can the investigators banish Abhoth?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## The Investigators can block the Gate that allows Abhoth into our world with an Elder Sign.

Abhoth was brought into the world. From the book *Dunwich: Return to the Forgotten Village*:

> Long before the advent of mankind, beings came to this place to make use of the natural magical energies found in the valley. The Mi-Go used these natural rifts between worlds to open a vast gate far below the surface, allowing a great, alien being to partially enter this world.
>
> This being was later known as Abhoth, Source of Uncleanness...

Abhoth can be driven back by dealing enough damage to it to drop it to zero hit points.

> **Abhoth** (from stat block):
>
> No weapon using kinetic force can harm Abhoth permanently. Abhoth regenerates from all kinetic damage at the rate of 20 points per melee round. Fire or magic will cause normal damage. ***If Abhoth is reduced to zero hit points, it withdraws and sinks far below the earth*** where it is inaccessible to further damage. It oozes again toward the surface after healing from its injuries.

Assuming that Abhoth can be driven back through the Gate, if the Investigators can cast the Elder Sign, the Gate would be sealed.

> **Elder Sign** (from the core rulebook 7th edition):
>
> An Elder Sign may be formed into a leaden seal, carved in rock, forged in steel, etc. When made active beside an opening or Gate, it makes that path unusable to minions of the Great Old Ones and Mythos Gods, as well as to those greater beings themselves.

*Terrors of the Secret War*, a source book for the game *Achtung! Cthulhu*, backs up the techniques outlined above.

> Because it is native to our dimension and dwells on our planet, Abhoth cannot be banished or truly killed; it was found or created here by the elder things, and used to fashion the first life on Earth. As a result, I fear there are only two ways to “defeat” Abhoth. The first is to strike some sort of a deal with it, as already mentioned. The second is to block its subterranean gates, sealing them with Elder Signs to prevent any spawn from coming through.

Comment: That technique is exactly why the Elder Sign exists.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to follow the rulebook, they could create a gate just under Abhoth, leading this abomination to another time/world/dimension

> **Gate Spells**
>
> *The idea of a panel that would open on some remote  world
>   impressed Eibon as being rather fantastic, not to say  farfetched.
>              — Clark Ashton Smith , The Door to Saturn*.
>
> Cost:   variable  POW  see   Table  XIII:  Gate  Creation  and   Travel Costs Cost  to 
>   access  a  Gate:   variable  magic  points  and  1  Sanity   point
>   Casting time:  one hour per POW spent Gate spells allow the caster to
>   create doorways between other  lands  or  times,  dimensions,  or 
>   worlds—allowing  the  user   to  travel  great  distances  with  a 
>   simple  step.  Usually  a  Gate   connects to a single other location.
>   Creation  of  a  Gate  requires  the  permanent  expenditure  of POW, in a sacrifice equal to the log to base 10 of the distance  the
>   Gate connects in miles times five. A Gate may take many  forms, 
>   common  ones  being  indicated  by  a  pattern  of  painted   lines on
>   a floor or a peculiar arrangement of stones in a field.  Using the
>   Gate costs a number of magic points equal to  one-fifth of the POW
>   originally used to make the Gate. Each  trip through a Gate costs 1
>   Sanity point. Should the user lack  enough magic points for a trip,
>   the traveler expends hit points  to make up the cost. Return trips
>   through a Gate always cost  the same as the initial journey.
>   Ordinarily,  anyone  or  anything  can  move  through  a  Gate, though some have been built so that a certain key—a word or 
>   gesture—is  needed  to  activate  the  portal.  Certain  versions  of 
>   the spell are known that also ‘change’ those who pass through,  to aid
>   survival on an alien world. There are also hints that some  Gates are
>   capable of more than one destination.

But you can create the spell you want, you know. The rulebook invites you to do it ! :

> **Spell Variations**
>
> There is no such thing as a definitive spell. The
>   ones listed  here  are  only  a  guide  and  starting  point  for  the
>   Keeper  to   draw upon.
>
> (...)
>
> **Altering a Spell**
>
> Try  to  insert  some  personal  touches  to  the 
>   spell,  tying  it   more  strongly  to  your  scenario, 
>   investigators,  and  story,  if   possible. Location:  consider  the 
>   locations  in  your  story;  could   one  of  them  be  linked  to 
>   the  spell?  If  the  investigators  are   dealing  with  ghouls,  for
>   example,  a  spell  that  must  be  cast   underground suddenly takes
>   on an added dimension. Spell  components:  the  specific  items 
>   required  to  cast   the spell. Could it be that the investigators
>   need the curved  silver dagger they saw in the previous session at the
>   British  Museum? Spell  ritual:  a  greater  spell  effect  usually 
>   means  a  more   complex  and  involved  ritual.  Consider  where, 
>   when,  and   how  the  spell  is  cast.  Do  the  investigators  have 
>   to  daub   themselves  in  blood  at  the  full  moon  and  inscribe 
>   a  ritual   circle? Spell description: this can range from subtle to
>   dramatic.  Try to imbue the description with strange smells,
>   disorient- ing visions, curious sounds, and disturbing sensations—re-
>   member  that  most  of  these  spells  erode  the  caster’s  sanity,
>   and the way in which you describe the casting should make  this
>   manifest

Comment: The module states that "Long before the advent of mankind, beings came to this place to make use of the natural magical energies found in the valley. The Mi-Go used these natural rifts between worlds to open a vast gate far below the surface, allowing a great, alien being to partially enter this world." So I guess there is already a gate open that allows Aboth in. Maybe the gate could just be closed?